# Why is the residue field called like that?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology, sheaf-theory

$\def\sO{\mathcal{O}}
\def\frm{\mathfrak{m}}
$If $(R,\frm)$ is a local ring, the field $R/\frm$ is called the residue field of $R$. More generally, let $(X,\sO_X)$ be a locally ringed space. The residue field of $X$ at $x$, denoted $\kappa(x)$, is the residue field of the local ring $\sO_{X,x}$. My question is: why is it called like that?

I guess this question may be answered in two possible directions:

1. Who came up with the name in the first place? Do we know their reasons for this choice of terminology?
2. What is a possible motivation that justifies why this name is a good fit for the idea behind the residue field?

In the particular cases where the locally ringed space $(X,\sO_X)$ is a smooth manifold, a complex manifold or a $k$-prevariety along with the corresponding structure sheaf of functions that are, respectively, real-valued smooth, complex-valued holomorphic, or $k$-valued regular, the homomorphisms $\sO_{X,x}\to\kappa(x)$ and $\sO(U)\to\kappa(x)$ (with $U\subset X$ an open neighborhood of $x$) are exactly evaluation at $x$. In this situation, I don't see what exactly the "residue" is. Neither I do in the case when $(X,\sO_X)$ is a variety (in the sense of schemes). The only residue field I know how to interpret in this case is the one at the generic point: It is the function field of the variety, but again I don't know what does this have to do with residues.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4271962/137524) has some discussion of the meaning of "residue field", but it's not evident whether it addresses the 'residue' terminology specifically. Myself I wonder if it might owe something to residues in complex analysis.

Comment: I think you're thinking of residues from complex analysis. I suspect this comes from number theory. Integers modulo a prime $p$ is called the residue and gives the residue field $Z/pZ$.

Comment: Residue, residual, reduction, remainder, this seems like random choices in a single lexical field.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Oxford Languages](https://languages.oup.com/google-dictionary-en/) *residue* means

"a small amount of something that remains after the main part has gone or been taken or used."

Among the synonims they give *remainder*.

When you mod out $\mathbb{Z}$ by the ideal $N\mathbb{Z}$ the elements in the quotient are just the (classes of the) remainders of division by $N$.

By analogy, you can say that the elements if $R/{\frak m}$ are what is left from elements of $R$ "after the part in $\frak m$ has been removed" and this should be the justification for the name of *residue field* (or *ring*)